# Dial a Number Twilio Number to Trigger TWILM Bin

Tags: twilio, twilio-php

We are attempting to create a workflow that will ultimately connect a lead from a contact form, with a business owner.

The workflow is as follows:
1) Lead fills in contact form
2) Using Stamplay integration with Unbounce, the lead receives a text asking them if they wanted to be contacted "Now", or "Later".

*Let's go with lead says "Now"*

3) Lead says "Now", which will access a webhook URL to decide on what to do next.

In this particular case, saying "Now", will trigger a TWIML bin to dial the business owner. If the business owner doesn't pick up/busy, then we send a text to the lead asking them to send a follow-up text with a 'name' and 'date/time'.

4) The lead replies with a text with this information, and then both the business owner and lead receive separate notifications about the appointment.

I have been able to successfully go through this whole workflow when a user directly dials the Twilio number (not programatically with keywords yet, which is where I need help).

**When a call comes in -> TWIML bin**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Response>
  <Pause length="4"/>
  <Say>Please hold, while I connect your call.</Say>
  <Pause length="4"/>
  <Dial timeout="10"> business owner number </Dial>
  <Pause length="4"/>
  <Sms>I am currently unavailable. If you'd like me to get in touch, pls reply back with your name, and a time that would work best for you. Thanks, Adam</Sms>
</Response>
```

**When a SMS is received -> webhook URL**

```
<?php
// Require the bundled autoload file - the path may need to change
// based on where you downloaded and unzipped the SDK
require __DIR__ . '/twilio-php-master/Twilio/autoload.php';

// Use the REST API Client to make requests to the Twilio REST API
use Twilio\Rest\Client;

// Your Account SID and Auth Token from twilio.com/console
$sid = 'xyz';
$token = 'xyz';
$client = new Client($sid, $token);

$number = $_POST['From'];
$body = $_POST['Body'];

//Sends a message to the owner
$sms = $client->account->messages->create(
    // Cell of owner
    '12345',
    array(
        // A Twilio phone number you purchased at twilio.com/console
        'from' => "78900",
        // Lead's reply sent to owner asNotification
        'body' => "Hi <name>. You have a new lead. The information for this lead is: $body. You can contact them at $number"
    )
);

//Sends a message to the lead
$sms = $client->account->messages->create(
    // Cell of Lead
    $number,
    array(
        // A Twilio phone number you purchased at twilio.com/console
        'from' => "78900",
        // Notification Message sent to Lead
        'body' => "This is a confirmation that I have received your information, and will be in contact with you soon. Thanks, <name>."
    )
);
```

Where I am encountering issues is having the lead text "Now", to trigger a phone call between the business owner and lead.

This is the code that I have been attempting to use, except that I have been receiving **11200- HTTP retrieval failure** non-stop. I have also attempted to use $client->account->calls->create, as that's what I used to successfully send messages.

```
// Read TwiML at this URL when a call connects (attempt to connect to owner)
$call = $client->calls->create(
  'lead-number', // Call this number
  '78900', // From a valid Twilio number
  array(
      'url' => TWIML Bin of Interest
  )
);
```

Anyone have any idea what I could do?

Answer (score 0):

Check out the example of [creating a dynamic response](https://www.twilio.com/docs/guides/sms/how-to-receive-and-reply-in-php#custom-responses-to-incoming-sms-messages):

```
<?php
// Get the PHP helper library from twilio.com/docs/php/install

require_once '/path/to/vendor/autoload.php'; // Loads the library
use Twilio\Twiml;

$response = new Twiml;
$body = $_REQUEST['Body'];

if( $body == 'hello' ){
    $response->message('Hi!');
}else if( $body == 'bye' ){
    $response->message('Goodbye');
}
print $response;
```

In your case you'll modify for if "now" is in the `$body` you can create the call which your code looks fine for.

```
$call = $client->calls->create(
    "+1415XXXXXXX", "+1415XXXXXXX",
    array("url" => "link_to_twiml_bin")
);
```

In regards to the 11200 HTTP retrieval error, take a look at the [possible solutions here](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/errors/11200#possible-solutions) especially:

> Make sure your web server allows HTTP POST requests to static
>   resources (if the URL refers to .xml or .html files)

Comment: Great thanks for getting to me on this Megan. Will check it out.